# Needed power to make an antenna work

Tags: antenna

A dipole antenna with a frequency of 90Mhz has a wavelength of approximately 3.33103 meters and an antenna length of (=wavelength/2) 1.66 meters. The minimum voltage to make the antenna work will be depending on the efficiency of material and distance. Is it possible to make the antenna length shorter than what it should require as mentioned above with a smaller voltage to make use of transmitter antenna for 90Mhz radio communication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: There's no "minimum power". An antenna is a linear thing. It "works" with as arbitrarily little energy you put in (unless you're a quantum physicist, which I don't think you are).

Of course, the less power you put in, the less it puts out – proportionally. That's the thing with linearity.

Also, no, you cannot just change your antenna dimensions; that changes the frequencies at which the antenna is efficient at. (and has nothing to do with power.) You even say that you want a half-wavelength antenna, so what makes you think you can change the antenna length while keeping the wavelength?

It seems you should refresh a bit of antenna basics.

Comment: what if the transmitter antenna's length will be shortened but the oscillator is the same as  before, for example 90Mhz.

Comment: A shorter dipole can be compensated by adding loading coils, but as Marcus says, you lose efficiency. https://www.hamradiosecrets.com/short-dipole.html

Comment: exactly as glen says: you're making a worse antenna for your frequency. You can compensate for that by making it "electrically" longer, but at the expense of gain and bandwidth. No free lunch.